# Programmatically raise UI text fields when keyboard opens

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my current code, and it works, however on smaller devices, the fields are moved above the users display. How can I edit this to make sure the fields do not become hidden from the user? I stole some of this code from a tut by gregbarbosa, so an explanation with an answer would help greatly. Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: Storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var teamID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var scoutID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pinNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signin: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var diamondPic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nodextext: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var loginB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var moverL: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")

    // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@IBAction func loginTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var secretKey = userDefaults.stringForKey("secretkey")
    var team:String = teamID.text
    var scout:String = scoutID.text
    var password:String = pinNum.text


    var loginQuery = PFQuery(className:"User")
    loginQuery.whereKey("teamID", equalTo:team)
    loginQuery.whereKey("scoutID", equalTo:scout)
    loginQuery.whereKey("password", equalTo:password)
    loginQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects.count != 0 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondViewController", sender: self)
        } else if error == nil && objects.count == 0{
            var alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Login Error", message: "Your TeamID, ScoutID, or Password is inncorrect.",       delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")

            alert.show()

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var loginTapped: UIButton!


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications() -> Void {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() -> Void {
    println("Deregistering!")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info: Dictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize: CGSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size)!
    var buttonOrigin: CGPoint = self.loginB.frame.origin;
    var buttonHeight: CGFloat = self.loginB.frame.size.height;
    var visibleRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    visibleRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(visibleRect, buttonOrigin)) {
        var scrollPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, buttonOrigin.y - visibleRect.size.height + buttonHeight + 4)
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)

    }
    nodextext.hidden = true
    diamondPic.hidden = true
}

func hideKeyboard() {
    teamID.resignFirstResponder()   //FirstResponder's must be resigned for hiding keyboard.
    scoutID.resignFirstResponder()
    pinNum.resignFirstResponder()
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
    diamondPic.hidden = false
    nodextext.hidden = false
}

}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this. First, you could change the content offset of the scroll view manually when a UI Element becomes first responder. You can check for this using `UITextFieldDelegate` and the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method. This often proves to be difficult though. Another thing to do is to put all of your UI Elements in a table view and call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` when a UIElement such as a text field becomes first responder.

Comment: If I decided to use the table view, would it look like a table, or could I style it to look a little more user friendly?

Comment: You can style it however you want. Using static cells design your UI (unless you want it to be dynamic of course). You can turn off cell separators, and make it look as any normal view would

Comment: There are also other extensions that do this if you search the Internet a little bit

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to hide keyboard is to add resignFirstResponder (or call your hideKeyboard) in scrollView delegate method :

```
  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Hope this helps